# Java JNI sometimes with correct result sometimes not

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a structure in C that saves strings, something like a dictionary (doesn't save strings that has sub-strings in the dictionary)...
Now I want to call the function developed in C from Java. I create the "interface" JNI to call the C function in Java, and this work almost perfectly.

For example, in Java I have:

```
Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
if (dic.find("some") == false) {
    dic.add("some");
    System.out.println("'some' added");
}
if (dic.find("something") == false) {
    dic.add("something");
    System.out.println("'something' added");
}
```

Sometimes my program print only **"'some' added"**, sometimes print **"'some' added"** and **"'something' added"**... The correct result is print only **"'some' added"**, because the second word has the sub-string 'some', so the second word should not be inserted in dictonary!

Why this happen?! Why sometimes the program returns the right result and sometimes not?!

---

### -- **Update** --

**Example.java**

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) // why 1000? To test the resistance of the JNI implementation
        {
            DicJNI dicJNI = new dicJNI();
            dicJNI.create();

            if (!dicJNI.search("some")) {
                dicJNI.insert("some");
                System.out.println("some added!");
            }
            if (!dicJNI.search("something")) {
                dicJNI.insert("something");
                System.out.println("something added!");
            }

            dicJNI.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**DicJNI.java**

```
public class DicJNI
{
    public native boolean   createDic();
    public native void      deleteDic();
    public native boolean   searchDic(String s);
    public native void      insertDic(String s);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("DicJNI_linux_x86_64");
    }

    private DicJNI dicJNI;

    public boolean create() {
        dicJNI = new DicJNI();
        return dicJNI.createDic();
    }

    public void delete() {
        dicJNI.deleteDic();
    }

    public boolean search(String s) {
        return dicJNI.searchDic(s);
    }

    public void insert(String s) {
        dicJNI.insertDic(s);
    }
}
```

**org_dic_DicJNI.h**

```
#include <jni.h>

#ifndef _Included_org_dic_DicJNI
#define _Included_org_dic_DicJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_createDic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_deleteDic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_searchDic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_insertDic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_Dic_DicJNI_XDic
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**org_dic_DicJNI.c**

```
#include "org_dic_DicJNI.h"
#include "dic.h"

#define false   0
#define true    1

dic d = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_createDic
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    d = dic_new();

    if (d == NULL)  return false;
    else            return true;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_deleteDic
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    dic_free(d);
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_searchDic
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring s)
{
    if (!dic_search(d, s)) {
        return false;   // Not Found
    }
    else {
        return true;    // Found
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_dic_DicJNI_insertDic
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring s)
{
    dic_add(d, s);
}

int main() { return 0; }
```

With this, sometimes I only have "some added!" and sometimes "some added!" and "something added!", I cannot understand why this happen! :(

Comment: the dic.find method implementation should reveal the answers. We have to track as to why dic.find("something") is false..

Comment: I update the first post with a real example of my code...

Comment: Even with the update we cannot be certain that dic_search(d, s) is working properly

Comment: I think I could solve the problem. In dic_search I change malloc for calloc! Apparently now it's working properly... :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a better way to write that:

```
Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
if (!dic.find("some")) {
    dic.add("Porto");
    System.out.println("'some' added");
}
if (!dic.find("something")) {
    dic.add("Porto");
    System.out.println("'something' added");
}
```

After re-reading I agree w/ G_H, might want to double check dic.find().

Comment: I have 99.9% of confidence int the C code, because it has a lot of testing... How can happen if(false == false) ?

Comment: True that doing `== false` or `== true` isn't good style, but in his case I think he wants to do something on false rather than true. So even if it's dodgy code, it should work or at least give consistent results. There must be an issue with the actual implementation of `Dictionary.find`.

Comment: @zecapistolas The expression `false == false` is always gonna be true. So if `find` returns false (i.e. not found, assuming the name of the method can be trusted) the expression in the `if` statement will be true and the code block will execute. Is that what you want? Anyway, you should use either `if(dic.find(...))` or `if(!dic.find(...))` depending on what you want to happen.

Comment: @zmf Hahaha, I think we're getting stuck in some edit loop :D